# ACO Node Duplication using Cake's aco_sync

Tags: cakephp

I have (for the sake of simplicity) 3 controllers:

```
AppController
    - action
    - anotherAction

PostsContoller
    - index
    - add

UsersController
    - index
    - add
    - edit
```

If I run `./lib/Cake/Console/cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync` I get the following:

```
Created Aco node: controllers/PostsController
Created Aco node: controllers/PostsController/index
Created Aco node: controllers/PostsController/add
Created Aco node: controllers/PostsController/action
Created Aco node: controllers/PostsController/anotherAction
Created Aco node: controllers/UsersController
Created Aco node: controllers/UsersController/index
Created Aco node: controllers/UsersController/add
Created Aco node: controllers/UsersController/edit
Created Aco node: controllers/UsersController/action
Created Aco node: controllers/UsersController/anotherAction
```

In other words, the two actions in my AppController are getting picked up once for each of the other controllers by aco_sync

Is this normal, or does it point to some configuration error somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal. If you define your controllers as `class PostsController extends AppController` and `class UsersControllers extends AppController`, then the two classes inherit AppController's methods (note: only public and protected methods, not private methods).

You can also call `$this->action()` and `$this->anotherAction()` from PostsController and UsersController.

This is how inheritance works.

Comment: Thanks @deimoks - I just don't remember seeing it in previous Cake versions so I thought I may have done something wrong this time around.